# How to group records by a two-value column ignoring small gaps?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

I have a subquery with a column named `code` that only has 1 and 0 values and an `ID` column because I query a lot of codes for each ID. I want to group by said column (and by `ID`) and by ocurrence but want to ignore groups with less than 3 records, so that bigger groups get merged.

I use `ROW_NUMBER() - ROW_NUMBER() over (partition ...)` to generate a group number which I use to group records by, but sometimes the records get mixed up caused by a coincidence in the sequence of the row number and the partitioned row number. This is an example

```
code | row_number | row_number_partition_by_code | group_number
------------------------------------------------------------------
  0  |     1      |             1                |     0
  0  |     2      |             2                |     0
  1  |     3      |             1                |     2
  1  |     4      |             2                |     2
  0  |     5      |             3                |     2
  1  |     6      |             3                |     3
  0  |     7      |             4                |     3
  0  |     8      |             5                |     3
  0  |     9      |             6                |     3
  0  |     10     |             7                |     3
  1  |     11     |             4                |     7
  0  |     12     |             1                |     0
```

As you can see, some groups contain both codes!

After this, I do

```
GROUP BY group_number 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 2
```

to eliminate small groups, and generate another group number to merge adjacent groups.

How can I group these values homogeneously?

**More Details**

All records are ordered by `ID` and by date (the later in descending order) in every `ROW_NUMBER()`.

The final result I expect is the time in minutes of the latest code group for each `ID`, and merging groups that are separated by less than 3 minutes.

I'm more interested in the groups with the value 1, so if the latest code group is a 0 ( considering it is not a couple minutes long ) then ignore that `ID` completely.

Usually, there is one record per minute. Sometimes it can take hours without a record for any `ID`

Comment: Please add the desired result. And CREATE TABLE and INSERTs  to reproduce your example.

Comment: Best approach is to determine group at the time of table populate.BTW how can you group them without using recursive CTE in sql servver 2008 ?can you share query ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh I've never thought of that, looks like a good idea. As of the query, I use 3 nested subqueries like so:  `SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT ... FROM (...)  tTwo ) tThree ...` First select assigns a code to every row. Second select creates a group number for every row. Third select groups by that group number, filters groups with less than 3 records and generates another group number. Fourth select groups by again (merging adjacent groups)

Comment: any problem in implementing my idea then ping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set up next example according to your data and your explanations:

> All records are ordered by ID and by date (the later in descending order)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, code int, dt datetime);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:10:40'),
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:09:10'),
  (1, 1, '20180112 10:08:15'),
  (1, 1, '20180112 10:06:00'),
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:05:00'),
  (1, 1, '20180112 10:04:55'),
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:03:40'),
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:03:30'),
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:03:20'),
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:02:10'),
  (1, 1, '20180112 10:01:30'),
  (1, 0, '20180112 10:01:15');
```

IMHO this is more about GROUPING AND WINDOW than GAPS AND ISLANDS. You can set the groups in this way:

```
SELECT id, code, dt,
       SUM(rst) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, dt DESC) grp
FROM   (SELECT id, code, dt,
               IIF(COALESCE(LAG(code) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, dt DESC), -1) <> code, 1, 0) rst
        FROM   tbl) x;
```

> ```
> id | code | dt                  | grp
> -: | ---: | :------------------ | --:
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:10:40 |   1
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:09:10 |   1
>  1 |    1 | 12/01/2018 10:08:15 |   2
>  1 |    1 | 12/01/2018 10:06:00 |   2
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:05:00 |   3
>  1 |    1 | 12/01/2018 10:04:55 |   4
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:03:40 |   5
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:03:30 |   5
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:03:20 |   5
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:02:10 |   5
>  1 |    1 | 12/01/2018 10:01:30 |   6
>  1 |    0 | 12/01/2018 10:01:15 |   7
> ```

Once you have the groups you can calculate time difference of each group:

```
SELECT id, code, grp, MAX(dt) maxDT, MIN(dt) minDT,
       DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(dt), MAX(dt)) as minutes
FROM (
      SELECT id, code, dt,
             SUM(rst) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, dt DESC) grp
      FROM   (SELECT id, code, dt,
                     IIF(COALESCE(LAG(code) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, dt DESC), -1) <> code, 1, 0) rst
              FROM   tbl) x
      ) y
GROUP BY id, code, grp
ORDER BY id, grp;
```

> ```
> id | code | grp | maxDT               | minDT               | minutes
> -: | ---: | --: | :------------------ | :------------------ | ------:
>  1 |    0 |   1 | 12/01/2018 10:10:40 | 12/01/2018 10:09:10 |       1
>  1 |    1 |   2 | 12/01/2018 10:08:15 | 12/01/2018 10:06:00 |       2
>  1 |    0 |   3 | 12/01/2018 10:05:00 | 12/01/2018 10:05:00 |       0
>  1 |    1 |   4 | 12/01/2018 10:04:55 | 12/01/2018 10:04:55 |       0
>  1 |    0 |   5 | 12/01/2018 10:03:40 | 12/01/2018 10:02:10 |       1
>  1 |    1 |   6 | 12/01/2018 10:01:30 | 12/01/2018 10:01:30 |       0
>  1 |    0 |   7 | 12/01/2018 10:01:15 | 12/01/2018 10:01:15 |       0
> ```

Then if I understand your comment correctly:

> I'm more interested in the groups with the value 1, so if the latest code group is a 0 ( considering it is not a couple minutes long ) then ignore that ID completely.

Rows can be filtered and get last row using:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
       id, code, grp, MAX(dt) maxDT, MIN(dt) minDT,
       DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(dt), MAX(dt)) as minutes
FROM (
      SELECT id, code, dt,
             SUM(rst) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, dt DESC) grp
      FROM   (SELECT id, code, dt,
                     IIF(COALESCE(LAG(code) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, dt DESC), -1) <> code, 1, 0) rst
              FROM   tbl) x
      ) y
GROUP BY id, code, grp
HAVING   (code = 0 AND DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(dt), MAX(dt)) >= 2)
         OR code = 1
ORDER BY id, grp DESC;
```

> ```
> id | code | grp | maxDT               | minDT               | minutes
> -: | ---: | --: | :------------------ | :------------------ | ------:
>  1 |    1 |   6 | 12/01/2018 10:01:30 | 12/01/2018 10:01:30 |       0
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f6f04b3575d8440a3cdaf8b9edd3ee8b)*</kbd>

Comment: Thank you and sorry if I my explanation was confusing. The fiddle shows it works, but I have sql server 2008 and LAG function is not available to me.

Comment: A self join can work as an alternative to LAG

Comment: Or an scalar subquery.